How do we solve the ODE $(2y+x)y' + 2 = y^2 + xy - y$ according to the substitution $v = y^{2} + yx$?
I am attempting to perform the following substitution in the non-linear ODE below:
$$
v=y^2+yx
$$
$$
(2y+x)y'+2=y^2+xy-y
$$
After attempting a multitude of different approaches, I still am unable to express the ODE fully in terms of only v and its derivatives AND making the ODE linear. The best attempt I have so far is the following:
$$
v'=d/dx[y^2+xy]=y
$$
$$
v''=y'
$$
$$
(2v'+x)v''+2=v-v'
$$
The problem is that in this form the ODE is still not linear, which makes the substitution useless. I have tried tweaking the equation and then performing the above v' and v'' substitution but to no avail. In some way or another I need to divide the (2+) term in front of y' which then makes the whole expression messy and to my ability impossible to express as a linear ODE.
Any help or guidance for the correct approach to this substitution is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Correct me if I am wrong but $$v'=\frac{d(y^2+xy)}{dx}=(x+2y)y'+y $$, not $\frac{\partial(y^2+xy)}{\partial x}=y$

@Gwen That would be very convenient indeed, but how did you get (+2)′ from just y^2 derived with respect to dx. I'd expect that term to become 0 as there is no x in it at all and it just acts as a constant.

But isn't y=f(x)? If it's a constant, then $v''=y'$ makes no sense as then $v''=0$

Thanks for this! Due to my inexperience with ODEs I was treating y like a variable not a function y(x) by habit. The derivative now makes sense.

I think you're doing some mistake. I'm continuing from my comment.
$$v=y^2+xy \implies v'=2y y' + xy' + y \\
\implies v'=(2y+x)y'+y$$
So your equation becomes
$$v'+2=v \implies dv=(v-2) dx$$
$$\implies \frac{dv}{v-2}=dx$$
Integrating both sides, we get
$$\ln |v-2|={x+C}\\ \implies |v-2|=e^{x+C}=C_1e^x\\\implies \frac{|y^2+xy-2|}{e^x}=C_1$$
Assuming $y^2+xy>2$,
$$\frac{y^2+xy-2}{e^x}=C_1$$

HINT
If we arrange the proposed ODE, one obtains the following ODE
\begin{align*}
(2y + x)y' + 2 = y^{2} + xy - y & \Longleftrightarrow 2yy' + xy' + y + 2 = y^{2} + xy\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y^{2})' + (xy)' + 2 = y^{2} + xy\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y^{2} + xy)' + 2 = y^{2} + xy\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow v' + 2 = v\\\\
\end{align*}
where $v = y^{2} + xy$.
Can you take it from here?

I think you're doing some mistake. According to your answer, $\frac{y^2+xy}{e^x}=C_1$, but that doesn't return the original equation. I think it should be $v'+2=v$

Okay never mind you edited it
